# Return 1 result with left join from table B

Tags: sql

```
Table A   Table B   Table B     Table B
Itemnr    Itemnr    Item Status     Remark
100000    100000    1               Approved
200000    100000    2               Use up
          100000    3               Obsolete
          200000    1               Approved
          200000    2               Use up
          200000    3               Obsolete
```

I would like to see only one result per line in table A item with as result the Remark based on Item status 1. I tried a lot with the option of a left join but without the good result.

Comment: Hi, please tag a database you are using ? Show us the expeced result and also it would be nice to show us what have you tried ?

Comment: What if more than one row in `table2` has a status of 1?

Comment: Can there be multiple rows (with different remarks) with status 1 in table b for a given Itemnr?  If so and you want only one row by itemnr with the remarks combined, you need to specify the database as the syntax varies.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.itemnr, b.remark
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on b.itemnr = a.itemnr and b.item_status = 1
```

If some records in `tablea` might not have a corresponding row in `tableb` with `item_status = 1` and you want to keep these in the resultset, then you can use `left join` instead of `inner join`.

Comment: I have taken less information now in my sql and this works. But in my final file there are more left joins. If I put in more left joins to other tables it generates more of the same itemnumbers. Wat can the reason be, what mistake do I make?

Comment: @MTH: one of your joins generates multiple columns (ie there is more than one row that matches on the join condition). It is impossible to tell exactly what without seeing sample data and expected results - you might want to ask a *new* question for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select t.*
from (select a.*, b.*, row_number() over (partition by a.itemr order by b.status) as seq
      from a inner join
           b
           on a.itemr = b.itemr
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

This will return rows total `itemr`s along with first `status`. Also this assumes `Itemnr, Item Status, Remark` are the columns name.

**EDIT :** If you want to check, first status `1` is available or not then you can do :

```
SELECT a.itemr, b.remark
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b
     ON b.itemr = a.itemr AND b.status = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the data example you have provided, you don't need `tablea`:

```
select b.itemnr, b.remark
from tableb b
where b.item_status = 1;
```

You specify that you want a `left join`, which implies rows in `tablea` that are not in `tableb`, although you have no such examples in the question.  In that case:

```
select a.itemnr, b.remark
from tablea a left join
     tableb b
     on b.itemnr = a.itemnr and b.item_status = 1;
```